# jQuery Datepicker error displaying

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a PHP function that gets dates from a database that need to be highlighted and disabled on the date picker.

I have a function that works if I declare the dates like

```
var disabledDates = ["12-02-2015"];
```

but when I try using

```
var disabledDates = <?php echo $date_list); ?>;
```

the date picker disappeared from the screen. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

So are you saying that when there are no dates to be disabled the final output on that line is:

```
var disabledDates = ;
```

If this is the case then there will be a javascript parser error on that line and any following javascript won't be executed which means the datepicker will never be created.

Comment: Hmm i see. Is there any way i could have some pre set in var disabledDates and then add the database dates to that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and make json with string concatenation, use `json_encode` instead:

`$ date_list = json_encode($dates);`

That way you will always have valid json even if `$dates` is empty

Comment: What does the generated javascript look like when you use json_encode?

Comment: when i do var_dump on $date_list i get string(14) "["20-02-2015"]"

Comment: Sure, but what does the actual javascript variable declaration look like?

Comment: Are you talking about what i get in the console? if so i get Mixed Content: The page at 'https://' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'. ...This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
bookholiday.php:189... Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <